# When is -XAllowAmbiguousTypes appropriate?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ambiguous-types

I've recently posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448150/techniques-for-tracing-constraints) about [syntactic-2.0](https://github.com/emilaxelsson/syntactic) regarding the definition of `share`. I've had this working in **GHC 7.6**:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeOperators, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Data.Syntactic
import Data.Syntactic.Sugar.BindingT

data Let a where
    Let :: Let (a :-> (a -> b) :-> Full b)

share :: (Let :<: sup,
          sup ~ Domain b, sup ~ Domain a,
          Syntactic a, Syntactic b,
          Syntactic (a -> b),
          SyntacticN (a -> (a -> b) -> b) 
                     fi)
           => a -> (a -> b) -> b
share = sugarSym Let
```

However, GHC 7.8 wants `-XAllowAmbiguousTypes` to compile with that signature. Alternatively, I can replace the `fi` with

```
(ASTF sup (Internal a) -> AST sup ((Internal a) :-> Full (Internal b)) -> ASTF sup (Internal b))
```

which is the type implied by the fundep on `SyntacticN`. This allows me to avoid the extension. Of course this is

- a very long type to add to an already-large signature
- tiresome to manually derive
- unnecessary due to the fundep

My questions are:

1. Is this an acceptable use of `-XAllowAmbiguousTypes`?
2. In general, when should this extension be used? An answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461560/how-can-i-extract-this-polymorphic-recursion-function/23462397#23462397) suggests "it is almost never a good idea".
3. Though I've read [the docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.2/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#ambiguity), I'm still having trouble deciding if a constraint is ambiguous or not. Specifically, consider this function from Data.Syntactic.Sugar:

   ```
   sugarSym :: (sub :<: AST sup, ApplySym sig fi sup, SyntacticN f fi) 
            => sub sig -> f
   sugarSym = sugarN . appSym
   ```

   It appears to me that `fi` (and possibly `sup`) should be ambiguous here, but it compiles without the extension. Why is `sugarSym` unambiguous while `share` is? Since `share` is an application of `sugarSym`, the `share` constraints all come straight from `sugarSym`.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot just use the inferred type for `sugarSym Let`, which is `(SyntacticN f (ASTF sup a -> ASTF sup (a -> b) -> ASTF sup b), Let :<: sup) => f` and does not involve ambiguous type variables?

Comment: @kosmikus Sorrt it took so long to respond. [This code](http://lpaste.net/105654) doesn't compile with the inferred signature for `share`, but *does* compile when either of the signatures mentioned in the question is used. You question was also asked in the comments of a [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23332255/xincoherentinstances-doesnt-work)

Comment: I would be very hesitant allowing ambiguous types in Haskell. A lot of its magic comes from its very strong type system. I don't know if some convenience is worth dealing with possible undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MorphingDragon If you know of any "possible undefined behavior" due to `-XAmbiguousTypes`, please explain. Even the dreaded `-XIncoherentInstances` doesn't lead to *undefined* behavior.

Comment: Undefined behavior probably isn't the most apt term. It's hard to understand just based off one program. The problem is deciability and GHCI not being able to prove the types in your program. 
There's a long discussion that might interest you on just this subject. http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2008-April/041397.html

Comment: As for (3), that type isn't ambiguous because of the Functional Dependencies in the definition of SyntacticN (i.e., f -» fi) and ApplySym (in particular, fi -> sig, sup). From that, you get that `f` alone is sufficient to fully disambiguate `sig`, `fi`, and `sup`.

Comment: @user2141650 Sorry it  took so long to reply. You're saying the fundep on `SyntacticN` makes `fi` unambiguous in `sugarSym`, but then why is the same not true for `fi` in `share`?

Comment: It isn't `fi` that's ambiguous in `share`, it's `sup`. That's why expanding `fi` fixes the issue - it uses the fundep to disambiguate `sup`. To figure this out, work recursively on the LHS (of `=>`) - seeing at each stage whether a type variable is equal to the RHS, constrained by a fundep, or constrained by variables that you've at previous steps shown to be thus constrained.

Comment: @user2141650, `sup` is determined by the fact that it is constrained to be `Domain a` (and `Domain b`). You can easily remove `sup` from the type signature and get the same error. The full error says something about overlapping instances for `SyntacticN b fi`, which would probably be illuminating for those who are familiar with the syntactic library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see any published version of syntactic whose signature for `sugarSym` uses those exact type names, so I'll be using [the development branch at commit 8cfd02^](https://github.com/emilaxelsson/syntactic/tree/8cfd021b8560a951b169cdaf0ac69a838e77de%5E), the last version which still used those names.

So, why does GHC complain about the `fi` in your type signature but not the one for `sugarSym`? The documentation you have linked to explains that a type is ambiguous if it doesn't appear to the right of the constraint, unless the constraint is using functional dependencies to infer the otherwise-ambiguous type from other non-ambiguous types. So let's compare the contexts of the two functions and look for functional dependencies.

```
class ApplySym sig f sym | sig sym -> f, f -> sig sym
class SyntacticN f internal | f -> internal

sugarSym :: ( sub :<: AST sup
            , ApplySym sig fi sup
            , SyntacticN f fi
            ) 
         => sub sig -> f

share :: ( Let :<: sup
         , sup ~ Domain b
         , sup ~ Domain a
         , Syntactic a
         , Syntactic b
         , Syntactic (a -> b)
         , SyntacticN (a -> (a -> b) -> b) fi
         )
      => a -> (a -> b) -> b
```

So for `sugarSym`, the non-ambiguous types are `sub`, `sig` and `f`, and from those we should be able to follow functional dependencies in order to disambiguate all the other types used in the context, namely `sup` and `fi`. And indeed, the `f -> internal` functional dependency in `SyntacticN` uses our `f` to disambiguate our `fi`, and thereafter the `f -> sig sym` functional dependency in `ApplySym` uses our newly-disambiguated `fi` to disambiguate `sup` (and `sig`, which was already non-ambiguous). So that explains why `sugarSym` doesn't require the `AllowAmbiguousTypes` extension.

Let's now look at `sugar`. The first thing I notice is that the compiler is *not* complaining about an ambiguous type, but rather, about overlapping instances:

```
Overlapping instances for SyntacticN b fi
  arising from the ambiguity check for ‘share’
Matching givens (or their superclasses):
  (SyntacticN (a -> (a -> b) -> b) fi1)
Matching instances:
  instance [overlap ok] (Syntactic f, Domain f ~ sym,
                         fi ~ AST sym (Full (Internal f))) =>
                        SyntacticN f fi
    -- Defined in ‘Data.Syntactic.Sugar’
  instance [overlap ok] (Syntactic a, Domain a ~ sym,
                         ia ~ Internal a, SyntacticN f fi) =>
                        SyntacticN (a -> f) (AST sym (Full ia) -> fi)
    -- Defined in ‘Data.Syntactic.Sugar’
(The choice depends on the instantiation of ‘b, fi’)
To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
```

So if I'm reading this right, it's not that GHC thinks that your types are ambiguous, but rather, that while checking whether your types are ambiguous, GHC encountered a different, separate problem. It's then telling you that if you told GHC not to perform the ambiguity check, it would not have encountered that separate problem. This explains why enabling AllowAmbiguousTypes allows your code to compile.

However, the problem with the overlapping instances remain. The two instances listed by GHC (`SyntacticN f fi` and `SyntacticN (a -> f) ...`) do overlap with each other. Strangely enough, it seems like the first of these should overlap with any other instance, which is suspicious. And what does `[overlap ok]` mean?

I suspect that Syntactic is compiled with OverlappingInstances. And looking at [the code](https://github.com/emilaxelsson/syntactic/blob/f29d78e51b43699cbb6d9a911b9b286081c763cd/src/Data/Syntactic/Sugar.hs#L1), indeed it does.

Experimenting a bit, it seems that GHC is okay with overlapping instances when it is clear that one is strictly more general than the other:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}

class Foo a where
  whichOne :: a -> String

instance Foo a where
  whichOne _ = "a"

instance Foo [a] where
  whichOne _ = "[a]"

-- |
-- >>> main
-- [a]
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ whichOne (undefined :: [Int])
```

But GHC is not okay with overlapping instances when neither is clearly a better fit than the other:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}

class Foo a where
  whichOne :: a -> String

instance Foo (f Int) where  -- this is the line which changed
  whichOne _ = "f Int"

instance Foo [a] where
  whichOne _ = "[a]"

-- |
-- >>> main
-- Error: Overlapping instances for Foo [Int]
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ whichOne (undefined :: [Int])
```

Your type signature uses `SyntacticN (a -> (a -> b) -> b) fi`, and neither `SyntacticN f fi` nor `SyntacticN (a -> f) (AST sym (Full ia) -> fi)` is a better fit than the other. If I change that part of your type signature to `SyntacticN a fi` or `SyntacticN (a -> (a -> b) -> b) (AST sym (Full ia) -> fi)`, GHC no longer complains about the overlap.

If I were you, I would look at [the definition of those two possible instances](https://github.com/emilaxelsson/syntactic/blob/f29d78e51b43699cbb6d9a911b9b286081c763cd/src/Data/Syntactic/Sugar.hs#L63) and determine whether one of those two implementations is the one you want.

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered that `AllowAmbiguousTypes` is very convenient for use with `TypeApplications`. Consider the function `natVal :: forall n proxy . KnownNat n => proxy n -> Integer` from [GHC.TypeLits](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#v:natVal).

To use this function, I could write `natVal (Proxy::Proxy5)`. An alternate style is to use `TypeApplications`: `natVal @5 Proxy`. The type of `Proxy` is inferred by the type application, and it's annoying to have to write it every time you call `natVal`. Thus we can enable `AmbiguousTypes` and write:

```
{-# Language AllowAmbiguousTypes, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}

ambiguousNatVal :: forall n . (KnownNat n) => Integer
ambiguousNatVal = natVal @n Proxy

five = ambiguousNatVal @5 -- no `Proxy ` needed!
```

However, note that once you go ambiguous, [you can't go back](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39772531/925978)!