# Ambiguous types with PolyKinds

Tags: haskell, ghc, higher-kinded-types

The following compiles *without* `PolyKinds`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, GADTs #-}

type family Modulus zq

type family Foo zq q

data Bar :: (* -> *) where
    Bar :: (zq' ~ Foo zq (Modulus zq)) => Bar (zq -> zq')
```

All appearances of `zq` are some type (kind `*`) representing modular arithmetic mod `q`. It'd be convenient to use `Nats` to represent these moduli. If I add `PolyKinds` and poly-kind the moduli in the type families:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, GADTs, PolyKinds #-}

type family Modulus zq :: k

type family Foo zq (q :: k)

data Bar :: (* -> *) where
    Bar :: (zq' ~ Foo zq (Modulus zq)) => Bar (zq -> zq')
```

GHC 7.8 complains:

```
Could not deduce (zq' ~ Foo zq (Modulus zq))
...
In the ambiguity check for:
  forall zq' zq. zq' ~ Foo zq (Modulus zq) => Bar (zq -> zq')
To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
In the definition of data constructor ‘Bar’
```

Did adding `PolyKinds` *really* make this ambiguous? Where is the ambiguity? Also related: [When is -XAllowAmbiguousTypes appropriate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684947/when-is-xallowambiguoustypes-appropriate)

If I throw GHC a bone and add `AllowAmbiguousTypes` the error moves from the declaration of the GADT to the *use* of the GADT (sans the suggestion to add the extension):

```
bar :: (zq' ~ Foo zq (Modulus zq))
  => Bar (zq -> zq')
bar = Bar
```

which makes me think using `AllowAmbiguousTypes` is a GHC red herring.

**EDIT**

To clarify, the types above might be instantiated as follows:

```
newtype Zq q = Zq Int
```

Then `zq ~ (Zq 3)`, `q ~ 3`, and `Modulus (Zq 3) ~ 3`, `Foo (Zq 3) 3 ~ (Zq 3)` (I stripped the work out of the `Foo` type family, so think of it as identity.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's restrict the `zq` arguments to kind `*` for the time being:

```
type family Modulus (zq :: *) :: k

type family Foo (zq :: *) (q :: k)
```

Then you get a slightly better error message that can be further improved by saying `-fprint-explicit-kinds` (assuming GHC 7.8):

```
Could not deduce ((~) * zq' (Foo k0 zq (Modulus k0 zq)))
from the context ((~) * zq' (Foo k zq (Modulus k zq)))
```

So the problem is that `Modulus` is polymorphic in its output kind, and `Foo` is polymorphic in its input kind. There's nothing that fixes this intermediate kind, so it remains ambiguous. One option to fix it is to use a `Proxy`:

```
import Data.Proxy

...

data Bar :: (* -> *) where
    Bar :: (m ~ Modulus zq, zq' ~ Foo zq m) => Proxy m -> Bar (zq -> zq')
```

Now you could even remove the `*` annotations for `Modulus` and `Foo` again and it would still work.

Comment: Interesting. As an alternative to adding `Proxy`, `AllowAmbiguousTypes` also works to resolve the declaration error. Is there a way to resolve the application error without using `Proxy`, for example by mangling the signature of `Bar`? I'm okay with using `AllowAmbiguousTypes` since presumably GHC will be able to make the necessary inferences from concrete applications.

Comment: Can I explicitly kind `Modulus zq :: k1` and `Modulus zq' :: k2` and use kind equality `k1 ~ k2`?

Comment: You could perhaps use a functional dependency instead: `class HasModulus (zq :: *) (m :: k) | zq -> m`. Here, the kind `k` is an "output", whereas in the kind-polymorphic type family `Modulus`, the kind `k` is an "input". Then `data Bar :: (* -> *) where Bar :: (HasModulus zq m, zq' ~ Foo zq m) => Bar (zq -> zq')` should work.

Comment: Hm, I guess I was hoping the type family would do something similar to the fundep. While the output kind of the `Modulus` type family is polymorphic, it is determined by its input. Is there a way to capture that with type families?