# Correct behaviour when in GHCI, type error when in file

Tags: haskell, types

Given the definition:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
 class Monad m => RunableMonad m where
   type ReturnType m :: * -> *
   run :: m a -> ReturnType m a
```

when I type in GHCI

```
:t \x -> [run $ return x]
```

it gives me correct type of expression:

```
\x -> [run $ return x] :: RunableMonad m => a -> [ReturnType m a]
```

but when I put definition the following definition into the file, it gives me a type error:

```
single :: RunableMonad m => a -> [ReturnType m a]
single x = [run $ return x]

Could not deduce (ReturnType m0 ~ ReturnType m)
from the context (RunableMonad m)
  bound by the type signature for
             single :: RunableMonad m => a -> [ReturnType m a]
  at concurrency-simulator.hs:467:11-49
NB: ‘ReturnType’ is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
Expected type: a -> [ReturnType m a]
  Actual type: a -> [ReturnType m0 a]
In the ambiguity check for:
  forall a (m :: * -> *). RunableMonad m => a -> [ReturnType m a]
To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
In the type signature for ‘single’:
  single :: RunableMonad m => a -> [ReturnType m a]
```

Comment: [Possibly related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684947/when-is-xallowambiguoustypes-appropriate)

Answer (score 3):

I think the result from GHCi's `:t` is essentially wrong in this case, and you will never be able to actually *use* the expression `run $ return x`.

The problem is that there is no restriction in your class definition that says that two different `Monad`s `m0` and `m` (to use the same names as your error message) cannot have the *same* `ReturnType`.

This means that when looking at the context in which `run $ return x` is used, GHC might be able to infer what the resulting `ReturnType m a` is, and from the type of `x` it can deduce what `a` is, but it cannot deduce from that what the actual monad `m` is.

You should however be able to tell it explicitly: `run (return x :: WhateverTypeYouReallyWant)`.

Adding an explicit type annotation should only be necessary when you are using `run` on an expression like `return x` which is so polymorphic it can belong to several monads.  (Or any monad, in this case.)

Answer (score 2):

You can make your code compile, but it will never be usable. Generally, if you see an error which recommends `AllowAmbiguosTypes`, this is a red herring. It will rarely fix your problem but will sometimes (as in this case) make it seem fixed:

```
{-# LANGUAGE 
  , ExistentialQuantification
  , TypeFamilies
  , FlexibleInstances
  , FlexibleContexts
  , ScopedTypeVariables
  , AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

class Monad m => RunableMonad m where
  type ReturnType m :: * -> *
  run :: m a -> ReturnType m a

single :: forall m a . RunableMonad m => a -> ReturnType m a
single x = run (return x :: m a)
```

But say I have:

```
import Data.Functor.Identity

instance RunableMonad Identity where 
  type ReturnType Identity = Identity
  run = id
```

this will produce extremely cryptic errors:

```
>:t single 'a' :: Identity Char

<interactive>:1:1:
    Couldn't match type `ReturnType m0' with `Identity'
    The type variable `m0' is ambiguous
    Expected type: Identity Char
      Actual type: ReturnType m0 Char
    In the expression: single 'a' :: Identity Char
```

To see why your function makes no sense, consider

```
instance RunableMonad [] where 
  type ReturnType [] = Identity
  run = Identity . head 

>:t single 'a'
single 'a' :: RunableMonad m => ReturnType m Char
```

How do you select which type class instance to use? You may falsely believe that since the `m` is still present in the type and you still have `RunableMonad m`, that this type says you can select any `m` which is a `RunableMonad`. But since `ReturnType` is a type function, and type functions are not injective, even if we have `ReturnType m Char ~ Identity Char`, we can't infer that `m ~ Identity` - it is obvious that this makes no sense when you take into account the fact that `m ~ []` would be a perfectly valid choice here.

It seems to me that the function `single` should not exist. The fact that the compiler originally rejects it is *completely correct*, and the fact that you can make it compile with `AmbiguousTypes` is a misfeature.

If you really must have your `single` function, you will have to do something like:

```
class Monad m => RunableMonad m where
  data ReturnType m a
  run :: m a -> ReturnType m a

instance RunableMonad Identity where 
  newtype ReturnType Identity a = RT_Id a deriving Show
  run (Identity a) = RT_Id a 

instance RunableMonad [] where 
  newtype ReturnType [] a = RT_List a deriving Show
  run = RT_List . head 

single x = run (return x) -- type here will be inferred
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have ghc 7.8, so this is only a guess.

I think you can try adding `AllowAmbiguousTypes` ,as the error message suggests, to

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

in the beginning of the source file, or look for a command line option of `ghc` for compiling with `AllowAmbiguousTypes`. I had a similar issue with GHCi and ghc command line having different behavior. It turned out that by default, ghci turns on a different set of options than ghc compiler. I ended up solving the problem by ensuring that the compile options and the interpreter options are the same for the feature in question.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't help. Error message is pretty much the same.