# Type application with ambiguous types

Tags: haskell, ghc

I recently discovered `-XTypeApplications`, which allows me to write abbreviate my code. Consider the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, DataKinds, KindSignatures, RankNTypes, 
             ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Tagged
import Data.Proxy

class Foo (a :: Bool) where
  foo :: Tagged a Int

instance Foo 'True where
  foo = 3

instance Foo 'False where
  foo = 4
```

instead of writing `proxy foo (Proxy::Proxy 'True)`, I can now write `untag $ foo @'True`, which saves me a lot of `Proxy` boilerplate. That's okay, but we can do better with ambiguous types:

```
foo' :: forall (a :: Bool) . (Foo a) => Int
foo' = untag $ foo @a
```

*Now* I can write `foo' @'True`! Note that although the type was ambiguous prior to `-XTypeApplications`, it is no longer since I can specify the type `a`. I think this is pretty great, but others might not. So I was hoping to introduce a wrapper

```
wrapAmbiguous :: forall (a :: Bool) b . (Foo a) => (forall (t :: Bool) . (Foo t) => b) -> Tagged a b
wrapAmbiguous f = Tagged $ f @a
```

(even more general in my actual use case, but this gets the point across), so that users don't need `-XTypeApplications`. However, when I try to use `wrapAmbiguous` like `proxy (wrapAmbiguous foo') (Proxy::Proxy 'True)`, I get the error

```
• Could not deduce (Foo a0) arising from a use of ‘foo'’
  from the context: Foo t
    bound by a type expected by the context:
               Foo t => Int
    at Foo.hs:26:18-35
  The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Foo 'False -- Defined at Foo.hs:12:10
    instance Foo 'True -- Defined at Foo.hs:9:10
• In the first argument of ‘wrapAmbiguous’, namely ‘foo'’
  In the first argument of ‘proxy’, namely ‘(wrapAmbiguous foo')’
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘proxy (wrapAmbiguous foo') (Proxy :: Proxy True)’
```

It seems to me that this should be legal, but GHC apparently can't unify the type of `foo'` with `forall (t :: Bool) (Foo t) => b`. Is there some way to make my wrapper work?

Comment: The weird thing is that it _is_ partly unifying the type of `foo'` since the error message tells us it has already figured out `b = Int`

Comment: The type of `foo'` is completely ambiguous, which means you always have to use a type application to specify the type variable. Inference can't figure it out because the `Foo a` in `foo'` can't ever unify with anything, as it doesn't appear in the type, only the context.

Comment: @user2407038 Does that observation inspire a solution?

Comment: could you rewrite the example without the Tagged library ?