# What is AllowAmbiguousTypes and why is it needed in this "forall" example?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, ambiguous-types

The code

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}

-- I know this particular example is silly.
-- But that's not the point here.
g :: forall a . RealFloat a => Bool
g = True

main :: IO ()
main = print (g @Double)
```

fails to compile on GHC 8.0 with the error

```
• Could not deduce (RealFloat a0)
      from the context: RealFloat a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   g :: RealFloat a => Bool
        at app/Main.hs:3:6-35
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘g’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      In the type signature:
        g :: forall a. RealFloat a => Bool
```

So adding `AllowAmbiguousTypes` will make the code compile.

Here are my questions:

- What exactly is `AllowAmbiguousTypes`?
- Why is it needed to make this particular code work?
- I fear that adding `AllowAmbiguousTypes` is giving me more than I really want in this particular code. It sounds scary. It sounds like it will make Haskell's type system less safe, perhaps in other areas that have nothing to do with this particular code. Are these fears unfounded?
- Are there any alternatives? In this case, it seems like Haskell is inserting a `a0` type variable that I never asked for. Is there no extension to tell Haskell not to create these extraneous type variables - and only use those that I explicitly told it to add with my own explicit `forall a`?
- Added one question because of [user2407038](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2407038/user2407038)'s comment: Would you say that `AllowAmbiguousTypes` is a misnomer? Would it have been better named as `AllowUnusedTypeVariables`?

Comment: An ambiguous type is one which has a type variable in its context which is not mentioned in the body (that to the right of `=>`) of the type. So `RealFloat a => ..` is ambiguous when `..` doesn't mention `a`. Ambiguous types are generally a programmer error, and before TypeApplications they were entirely useless, so you need an extension to allow them. For the last two questions: it doesn't make the typechecker 'unsafe' in any way; and your alternative is to write `RealFloat a => Proxy a -> Bool`, where [Proxy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html) is here.

Comment: As an alternative, you can use `RealFloat a => Tagged a Bool`, where `Tagged` comes from the `tagged` package, which can be more efficient than the proxy way under some circumstances.

Comment: `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, in my eyes, is harmless. In many lambda calculi, types are always passed explicitly (e.g. `map @a @b f xs`). In plain Haskell, types are inferred -- implying that we do not have to pass them (good), and we can not pass them even if we want (bad). Because of that, types with tyvars which can not be inferred from the types of the arguments or the return value must be forbidden. Hence we have to use proxies/tagged only to make them inferrable, adding clutter. However, now GHC allow explicit type applications, so we no longer have to do that.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684947/when-is-xallowambiguoustypes-appropriate).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> What exactly is `AllowAmbiguousTypes`?

From the [latest GHC docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ambiguous-types-and-the-ambiguity-check), "a type `ty` is ambiguous if and only if `((undefined :: ty) :: ty)` would fail to typecheck". The extension `AllowAmbiguousTypes` just disables this check - it won't allow ill-typed programs through.

> Why is it needed to make this particular code work?

In order to check that `RealFloat a` is satisfied whenever `g` is used, GHC needs to know what `a` is. You have not way (in vanilla Haskell<sup>1</sup>) of telling GHC what `a` should be since `a` occurs nowhere else in the type of `g`. No amount of annotations will let you use `g` without getting an ambiguous type variable error.

However, if you don't *use* `g` anywhere, you can still get your code to compile by turning on `AllowAmbiguousTypes`.

> I fear that adding `AllowAmbiguousTypes` is giving me more than I really want in this particular code. It sounds scary. It sounds like it will make Haskell's type system less safe, perhaps in other areas that have nothing to do with this particular code. Are these fears unfounded?

Yes they are: the ambiguity check lets you catch definitions which cannot (in vanilla Haskell, which doesn't have `TypeApplications`<sup>1</sup>) be used without resulting in an ambiguous type variable error. Disabling this check just means you will see the ambiguous type variable messages when you use the expression (or function) instead of at its definition site.

> Are there any alternatives? In this case, it seems like Haskell is inserting a `a0` type variable that I never asked for. Is there no extension to tell Haskell not to create these extraneous type variables - and only use those that I explicitly told it to add with my own explicit `forall a`?

The `a0` is coming from the ambiguity check I mentioned at the beginning of this answer. GHC just uses the name `a0` to make it clear it is different from `a`. The ambiguity check basically just tries to typecheck

```
((undefined :: forall a. RealFloat a => Bool) :: forall a0. RealFloat a0 => Bool)
```

`AllowAmbiguousTypes` removes this check. I don't think there is an extension that disables ambiguity checks only on type signatures with explicit `forall`s (although this might be neat and useful!).

> Would you say that `AllowAmbiguousTypes` is a misnomer? Would it have been better named as `AllowUnusedTypeVariables`?

Naming things is hard. :)

The current name references the type of errors you get without the extension enabled, so it isn't a bad name. I guess this is a matter of opinion. (A lot of people also wish `Monad` was called something like `FlatMapAble`.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Prior to `TypeApplications` (which is a relatively new extension from GHC 8.0), there really was no way of using expressions that triggered the ambiguity check without getting an ambiguous type variable error, so `AllowAmbiguousTypes` was a lot less useful.

Comment: `since a occurs nowhere else in the type of g` ← not only in type, but also doesn't occur in body. If you use `a` variable in body of function then you don't need `-XAllowAmbiguousTypes`.

Comment: @Shersh What do you have in mind? If you use the type variable in the body of the function (presumably with `ScopedTypeVariables` enabled) you don't pass into the type checker any more way to resolve what `a` should be at call sites...

Comment: Sorry. Somehow I'm wrong. When I tested code from this slide last year with ghc 8.0.1 it worked. But now it doesn't work without `-XAllowAmbiguousTypes`: http://slides.com/fp-ctd/lecture-15#/17 :(

Comment: Thank you. Almost perfect answer. However, can you elaborate a bit on why, without `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, `((undefined :: forall a. RealFloat a => Bool) :: forall a0. RealFloat a0 => Bool)` fails to typecheck, but for example `((undefined :: forall a. RealFloat a => a -> Bool) :: forall a0. RealFloat a0 => a0 -> Bool)` would successfully typecheck?

Comment: @haskellHQ `((undefined :: forall a. RealFloat a => Bool) :: forall a0. RealFloat a0 => Bool)` fails to type check because GHC has no way of unifying the two type variables (`a` and `a0`). In the case of `forall a0. RealFloat a => a -> Bool` and `forall a0. RealFloat a0 => a0 -> Bool`, GHC realizes `a ~ a0` based on comparing the two first parameters.

Comment: This explains everything. Thank you!