# Why is this type variable ambiguous, although it should be in scope?

Tags: haskell, type-families, type-variables

Consider the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
class Foo a where
  type Bar a

class Foo a => Foo2 a where
  bar :: Bar a
```

It gives the following error message in GHC 8.2:

```
 error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Bar a’ with actual type ‘Bar a0’
      NB: ‘Bar’ is a type function, and may not be injective
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘bar’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      When checking the class method: bar :: forall a. Foo2 a => Bar a
      In the class declaration for ‘Foo2’
  |
7 |   bar :: Bar a
  |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What's the problem? Why does it universally quantify over `a`? If I change the last line to

```
  bar :: a
```

the problem vanishes. Why doesn't it have the type variable `a` in scope otherwise?

(I looked through all "ambiguous type variable" questions now, but nothing seems to help.)

Comment: What did you change the last line to? Isn't `bar :: Bar a` just what it was from the start? typo?

Comment: @Alec, whoops, yes, thanks, corrected.

Comment: This has nothing to do with scope. From the [GHC docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ambiguous-types-and-the-ambiguity-check), "a type `ty` is ambiguous if and only if `((undefined :: ty) :: ty)` would fail to typecheck". In your case, as the error message suggests, `ty` is `forall a. Foo2 a => Bar a`. A more interesting question might be: _why_ does GHC report an error for what it calls "ambiguous type variables". For an answer to that, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/45664950/3072788.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine you make two `Foo` instances with the same associated type, and then defined

```
..
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications    #-}
..

instance Foo Int   where type Bar Int   = Bool
instance Foo Float where type Bar Float = Bool

instance Foo2 Int where
  bar :: Bool
  bar = False

instance Foo2 Float where
  bar :: Bool
  bar = True
```

This means that the type of `bar` is not enough to decide between the `Foo2 Int` and `Foo2 Float` instances.

```
bar :: Foo2 a => Bar a
```

GHC will attempt to infer the type `a` for you but if you ask for

```
bar :: Bool
```

it has no way to pick between `Int` / `Float` or any other instance that may come later. You must explicitly specify the type with `-XTypeApplications`

```
>>> :set -XTypeApplications
>>
>> bar @Int
False
>> bar @Float
True
```

---

**Edit**: If every instance of `Foo` is a different type (`Foo` is injective) you can specify that the result determines the instance type with this syntax `.. = res | res -> a`

```
..
{-# Language TypeFamilyDependencies #-}

class Foo a where
  type Bar a = res | res -> a
```

You can't define `Bar Int` and `Bar Float` both equal to `Bool`. If we only define `Foo Int` and `Foo2 Int` then `bar :: Bool` is enough to let GHC know you're looking for `bar @Int = False`.

Comment: Specifically, `bar :: Bool` incurs the constraint `Bar a ~ Bool`, but now you have `(Bar a ~ Bool) => Bool` with an `a` on the left and not on the right, and the non-injectivity of `Bar` means that the constraint is unsolvable as-is. The other possible solution is to bring `Bar` out of the class as its own type family `type family Bar a = r | r -> a` where the `TypeFamilyDependency` notation `| r -> a` (like a fundep) means that `Bar` is injective.

Comment: The crucial part of the error message is `NB: ‘Bar’ is a type function, and may not be injective`, i.e. given the result of `Bar a`, you can't determine `a`.

Comment: You don't need to bring `Bar` out of the class for that, I've added it to the answer