# Proof-tree from instance search in haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there anyway to trick haskell (raw haskell ? source plugins ? anything ?) to get a proof tree of how a type class was derived ?

What I would like, says using the exemple below :

```
**Diff**
           --      --
           Id      Id
----       ----------
Unit       Prod Id Id
---------------------
Sum Unit (Prod Id Id)
```

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-17.10 script

{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}

module SOShow where

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
import Data.Constraint
import Data.Typeable

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- universe of polynomial functors

data Zero a deriving (Show)

data Unit a = Unit deriving (Show)

data Id a = Id a deriving (Show)

data Sum s t a = Inl (s a) | Inr (t a) deriving (Show)

data Prod s t a = s a :*: t a deriving (Show)

magic :: Zero a -> b
magic z = seq z (error "This is magic")

instance Functor Unit where fmap f z = Unit

instance Functor Id where fmap f (Id a) = Id (f a)

instance (Functor s, Functor t) => Functor (Sum s t) where
  fmap f s = case s of (Inl s) -> Inl (fmap f s); (Inr s) -> Inr (fmap f s)

instance (Functor s, Functor t) => Functor (Prod s t) where fmap f (s :*: t) = fmap f s :*: fmap f t

-- TreeF

type TreeF = Sum Unit (Prod Id Id)

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- Derivatives

class Functor f => Diff f where
  type Δ f :: * -> *
  posns :: f a -> f (a, Δ f a)
  plug :: (a, Δ f a) -> f a

instance Diff Unit where
  type Δ Unit = Zero
  posns Unit = Unit
  plug (a, z) = magic z

instance Diff Id where
  type Δ Id = Unit
  posns (Id a) = Id (a, Unit)
  plug (a, Unit) = Id a

instance (Diff f, Diff g) => Diff (Sum f g) where
  type Δ (Sum f g) = Sum (Δ f) (Δ g)
  posns (Inl (x :: f a)) = Inl (fmap (\(a, dx) -> (a, Inl dx)) (posns x :: f (a, Δ f a)))
  posns (Inr y) = Inr (fmap (\(a, dy) -> (a, Inr dy)) (posns y))
  plug (a, Inl (x :: Δ f a)) = Inl (plug (a, x) :: f a)
  plug (a, Inr y) = Inr (plug (a, y))

instance (Diff f, Diff g) => Diff (Prod f g) where
  type Δ (Prod f g) = Sum (Prod (Δ f) g) (Prod f (Δ g))
  posns (x :*: y) = fmap (\(a, dx) -> (a, Inl (dx :*: y))) (posns x) :*: fmap (\(a, dy) -> (a, Inr (x :*: dy))) (posns y)
  plug (a, Inl (dx :*: y)) = plug (a, dx) :*: y
  plug (a, Inr (x :*: dy)) = x :*: plug (a, dy)

type B = Δ TreeF

-- > :k! B
-- B :: * -> *
-- = Sum Zero (Sum (Prod Unit Id) (Prod Id Unit))

w :: Dict (Diff TreeF) = Dict

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print w --Dict
  print (typeOf w) -- Dict (Diff (Sum Unit (Prod Id Id)))

{-
**Diff**
           --      --
           Id      Id
----       ----------
Unit       Prod Id Id
---------------------
Sum Unit (Prod Id Id)
-}
```

Comment: At the very least you could create a method of the class which returns the derivation, defining it for each instance (& maybe possible using a default signature & generics to implement it automatically)

Comment: Good idea. This witnesses "itself", and should be CPS'ed, to be "open" and allow further instances to extend the proof. There should be some neat type already for these kind of (pretty standard) constructions, with output to latex and whatnot..

Comment: Side note: no need for magic. Enable `EmptyCase` and use `magic x = case x of`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestion of @luqui, here's a sketch of what it could look like, for *your **own** typeclasses* (with a very dumb `ProofTree` type)

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-17.10 script

{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}

module SOShow3 where
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
import Data.Constraint
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Typeable

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- Proof trees

data ProofTree = Leaf String | Node1 String ProofTree | Node2 String ProofTree ProofTree | Node3 String ProofTree ProofTree ProofTree deriving (Show)

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- Universe of polynomial functors

data Zero a deriving (Show)

data Unit a = Unit deriving (Show)

data Id a = Id a deriving (Show)

data Sum s t a = Inl (s a) | Inr (t a) deriving (Show)

data Prod s t a = s a :*: t a deriving (Show)

magic :: Zero a -> b
magic z = case z of

instance Functor Unit where fmap f z = Unit

instance Functor Id where fmap f (Id a) = Id (f a)

instance (Functor s, Functor t) => Functor (Sum s t) where
  fmap f s = case s of (Inl s) -> Inl (fmap f s); (Inr s) -> Inr (fmap f s)

instance (Functor s, Functor t) => Functor (Prod s t) where fmap f (s :*: t) = fmap f s :*: fmap f t

-- TreeF
type TreeF = Sum Unit (Prod Id Id)

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- Derivatives

class Functor f => Diff f where
  type Δ f :: * -> *
  -- w :: Tagged f ProofTree -- without AllowAmbiguousTypes
  w :: ProofTree

instance Diff Unit where
  type Δ Unit = Zero
  w = Leaf "Unit"

instance Diff Id where
  type Δ Id = Unit
  w = Leaf "Id"

instance (Diff f, Diff g) => Diff (Sum f g) where
  type Δ (Sum f g) = Sum (Δ f) (Δ g)
  w = Node2 "Sum" (w @f) (w @g)

instance (Diff f, Diff g) => Diff (Prod f g) where
  type Δ (Prod f g) = Sum (Prod (Δ f) g) (Prod f (Δ g))
  w = Node2 "Product" (w @f) (w @g)

type DeltaTreeF = Δ TreeF

-- > :k! DeltaTreeF
-- DeltaTreeF :: * -> *
-- = Sum Zero (Sum (Prod Unit Id) (Prod Id Unit))

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- Prints (Δ TreeF) -- same as :k! in GHCI
  print (typeOf (Proxy :: Proxy (Δ TreeF))) -- Proxy (* -> *) (Sum Zero (Sum (Prod Unit Id) (Prod Id Unit)))

  -- TreeF verifies Diff
  let witness :: Dict (Diff TreeF) = Dict
  print (typeOf witness) -- Dict (Diff (Sum Unit (Prod Id Id)))

  -- TreeF verifies Diff - proof tree
  let r = w @TreeF
  putStrLn ("Proof tree : " ++ show r) --  Node2 "Sum" (Leaf "Unit") (Node2 "Product" (Leaf "Id") (Leaf "Id"))
```

Comments welcome.

Edit : removed useless CPS, removed Tagged with `AllowAmbiguousTypes` (quite safe despite the name, nice explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128492/what-is-allowambiguoustypes-and-why-is-it-needed-in-this-forall-example) on this)

Comment: [`type ProofTree = Tree String`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Graph.html#t:Tree)? Or is there actually a reason to limit the branching factor to at most 3?

Comment: you are right. I felt it might be confusing since I was looking into Tree in the first place in the context of `Diff`. I guess the best rep should be equipped with facilities for drawing / export to svg etc (?)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use of CPS? You wrote that you use that to make this open and ready to be extended, but I can't see why a non-CPS variant would prevent that. Maybe there are some (non-obvious to me) performance benefits?

Comment: @chi you are right. writing out why you are (obviously) right :  those instances are only **static** "client" and "server", entirely closed statically in haskell (I think - there are no phase of "partial" completion of instances (?) -- appart from haskell itself with its constraints -- ) and this cps is at value level,  so has nothing to do with static world. it's better to build the values directly..

Comment: nb : this is limited to my own typeclass, I wonder what could be done for type classes in general (including from external libraries)

Comment: To remove `Tagged`, you can  simply enable the `AllowAmbiguousTypes` extension and write `class ... where ... w :: ProofTree`, then remove all the uses of `Tagged` and `unTagged`. You already use `w @...` to choose the right instance, so everything will work fine.